# BuildFire WooCommerce Plugin Doesn't Work

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, buildfire

I want to add my products to my app with BuildFire WooCommerce Plugin. I read the documentation. I generate WooCommerce API Key in my web site. I added WooCommerce Plugin to my BuildFire app. And I fill the Store Url, Consumer Key, Secret Key

But I can't see my products. How can i solve this? Anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this plugin only supports the previous version of WooCommerce (1.x or 2.x).

Comment: Can i lower Woocommerce version in Wordpress? Or BuildFire have another plugin? Thanks